# Android Stack App crashes when viewing achievements

Tags: bug, android-app

I am using the Stack Exchange app (v1.0.71) on Android 4.1.2 with kernel version 3.4.0, on an LG Optimus F5.

The app crashes with "Unfortunately Stack Exchange has stopped" when I select the Achievements menu button. Everything else works properly. I can scroll through the feed, view questions, view my site and network profiles, view messages, and upvote comments. I have not tried to create a post since this behavior started.

The crash is only invoked when I tap the Achievements menu icon, and it has happened 100% of the times I've tried this action since the problem began, which was a couple of days ago.